# How to generate sophisticated Report by running Jmeter Scripts on Loadrunner 12.55

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I tried running my existing Jmeter Scripts on Load Runner, as the Jmeter Scripts (.jmx) are supported on Load Runner 12.55 onward. But not able to get a good report. I found only 4 Jmeter Graphs. Also, the Summary Report not displays complete information for the jmeter tests.

[image]

Can anybody help, how to use the Load Runner efficiently for running Jmeter scripts.

Comment: that's all that is supported, read the docs: https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/How-to-run-JMeter-test-in-LoadRunner-Performance-Center-12-55/ba-p/1619836#.WrvaHBPwbjA

Comment: Could you please send the graphs you would like to see via VuGen: Help->Send us your feedback

Answer (score 3):

Kiril S. is right the JMeter graphs in LoadRunner 12.55 are bit limited.
Yet, upgrading to LoadRunner 12.56 the "JMeter Transactions" and "Active Threads" moved to the standard "Transaction" and "Running VUsers" monitors.

Those graphs are more detailed.
See, [Announcing the release of LoadRunner and Performance Center 12.56](https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/Announcing-the-release-of-LoadRunner-and-Performance-Center-12/ba-p/1635107#.WryWVYhuZPY)

Also LoadRunner 12.56 supports JMeter Remote Testing which is very useful for heavy testing.